# PHP dynamical value as time() function speed in bigdata

Tags: php, arrays, time, bigdata

What is the preferred (less memory consuming and fastest) approach to use time() or any similar dynamic value in billion+ iterations?

A)

```
$time = time();
foreach($_billion_items_array as $_i => $_v) {
  if($_v['time_saved'] < $time + rand(1,100)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

B)

```
$this->time = time();

foreach($this->$_billion_items_array as $_i => $_v) {
  if($_v['time_saved'] < $this->time + rand(1,100)) {
    $this->do_something(_v);
  }
}
```

C)

```
$this->time = time();

function fixTime($_correction) {
  return $this->time + $_correction;
}

foreach($this->$_billion_items_array as $_i => $_v) {
  if($_v['time_saved'] < $this->fixTime(rand(1,100)) {
    $this->do_something(_v);
  }
}
```

I would personally prefer C) but I don't know how will PHP use memory, if every iteration is storing time as variable? Is it the same in A) and B)?

Comment: For a more exact value, you could use `microtime()` and skip `rand()` or keep it for even more reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is surely the fastest, because it uses the simplest way to access your `$time` variable inside your loop.

C is by far the slowest, because it must invoke your function on every iteration of the loop.

All your choices use roughly the same amount of RAM.

If you were doing 10^3 iterations, none of this would make much difference. But you are doing 10^9 interactions so you should simplify the code in your loop as much as you possibly can.

And, I think you want `foreach()` in place of `for()`.

Comment: For me is important to know that RAM values are same in all cases.